# BackendException: Backend Internal error: Exception during psi2ir : root cause java.lang.NullPointerException

Tags: android, kotlin, android-studio, android-jetpack-compose, build.gradle

I am trying to solve this error from last three days but getting no where. If someone knows how to solve this please let me know. Also, I am relatively newer to Android development so if i missed something let me know.

Complete stack trace:

```
org.jetbrains.kotlin.backend.common.BackendException: Backend Internal error: Exception during psi2ir
File being compiled: (190,29) in  MainActivity.kt
The root cause java.lang.NullPointerException was thrown at: org.jetbrains.kotlin.psi2ir.generators.OperatorExpressionGenerator.generateBinaryOperatorAsCall(OperatorExpressionGenerator.kt:536)
null: KtBinaryExpression:
**fadeIn(animationSpec = tween(300)) + scaleIn(initialScale = .85f)**
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.backend.common.CodegenUtil.reportBackendException(CodegenUtil.kt:239)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.psi2ir.generators.DeclarationGenerator.generateMemberDeclaration(DeclarationGenerator.kt:75)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.psi2ir.generators.DeclarationGenerator.generateClassMemberDeclaration(DeclarationGenerator.kt:101)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.psi2ir.generators.ClassGenerator.generateMembersDeclaredInClassBody(ClassGenerator.kt:496)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.psi2ir.generators.ClassGenerator.generateClass(ClassGenerator.kt:105)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.psi2ir.generators.ClassGenerator.generateClass$default(ClassGenerator.kt:67)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.psi2ir.generators.DeclarationGenerator.generateClassOrObjectDeclaration(DeclarationGenerator.kt:108)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.psi2ir.generators.DeclarationGenerator.generateMemberDeclaration(DeclarationGenerator.kt:53)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.psi2ir.generators.ModuleGenerator.generateSingleFile(ModuleGenerator.kt:67)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.psi2ir.generators.ModuleGenerator.generateModuleFragment(ModuleGenerator.kt:47)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.psi2ir.Psi2IrTranslator.generateModuleFragment(Psi2IrTranslator.kt:87)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.backend.jvm.JvmIrCodegenFactory.convertToIr(JvmIrCodegenFactory.kt:194)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.backend.jvm.JvmIrCodegenFactory.convertToIr(JvmIrCodegenFactory.kt:53)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.cli.jvm.compiler.KotlinToJVMBytecodeCompiler.convertToIr(KotlinToJVMBytecodeCompiler.kt:232)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.cli.jvm.compiler.KotlinToJVMBytecodeCompiler.compileModules$cli(KotlinToJVMBytecodeCompiler.kt:115)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.cli.jvm.compiler.KotlinToJVMBytecodeCompiler.compileModules$cli$default(KotlinToJVMBytecodeCompiler.kt:60)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.cli.jvm.K2JVMCompiler.doExecute(K2JVMCompiler.kt:157)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.cli.jvm.K2JVMCompiler.doExecute(K2JVMCompiler.kt:52)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.cli.common.CLICompiler.execImpl(CLICompiler.kt:94)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.cli.common.CLICompiler.execImpl(CLICompiler.kt:43)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.cli.common.CLITool.exec(CLITool.kt:101)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.incremental.IncrementalJvmCompilerRunner.runCompiler(IncrementalJvmCompilerRunner.kt:477)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.incremental.IncrementalJvmCompilerRunner.runCompiler(IncrementalJvmCompilerRunner.kt:127)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.incremental.IncrementalCompilerRunner.compileIncrementally(IncrementalCompilerRunner.kt:366)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.incremental.IncrementalCompilerRunner.compileIncrementally$default(IncrementalCompilerRunner.kt:311)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.incremental.IncrementalCompilerRunner.compileImpl$rebuild(IncrementalCompilerRunner.kt:111)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.incremental.IncrementalCompilerRunner.compileImpl(IncrementalCompilerRunner.kt:165)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.incremental.IncrementalCompilerRunner.compile(IncrementalCompilerRunner.kt:74)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.daemon.CompileServiceImplBase.execIncrementalCompiler(CompileServiceImpl.kt:625)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.daemon.CompileServiceImplBase.access$execIncrementalCompiler(CompileServiceImpl.kt:101)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.daemon.CompileServiceImpl.compile(CompileServiceImpl.kt:1739)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:77)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:568)
    at java.rmi/sun.rmi.server.UnicastServerRef.dispatch(UnicastServerRef.java:360)
    at java.rmi/sun.rmi.transport.Transport$1.run(Transport.java:200)
    at java.rmi/sun.rmi.transport.Transport$1.run(Transport.java:197)
    at java.base/java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(AccessController.java:712)
    at java.rmi/sun.rmi.transport.Transport.serviceCall(Transport.java:196)
    at java.rmi/sun.rmi.transport.tcp.TCPTransport.handleMessages(TCPTransport.java:587)
    at java.rmi/sun.rmi.transport.tcp.TCPTransport$ConnectionHandler.run0(TCPTransport.java:828)
    at java.rmi/sun.rmi.transport.tcp.TCPTransport$ConnectionHandler.lambda$run$0(TCPTransport.java:705)
    at java.base/java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(AccessController.java:399)
    at java.rmi/sun.rmi.transport.tcp.TCPTransport$ConnectionHandler.run(TCPTransport.java:704)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1136)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:635)
    at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:833)
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.psi2ir.generators.OperatorExpressionGenerator.generateBinaryOperatorAsCall(OperatorExpressionGenerator.kt:536)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.psi2ir.generators.OperatorExpressionGenerator.generateBinaryExpression(OperatorExpressionGenerator.kt:138)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.psi2ir.generators.StatementGenerator.visitBinaryExpression(StatementGenerator.kt:445)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.psi2ir.generators.StatementGenerator.visitBinaryExpression(StatementGenerator.kt:51)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.psi.KtBinaryExpression.accept(KtBinaryExpression.java:35)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.psi2ir.generators.StatementGenerator.generateStatement(StatementGenerator.kt:67)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.psi2ir.generators.BodyGenerator.generateLambdaBody(BodyGenerator.kt:115)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.psi2ir.generators.FunctionGenerator.generateLambdaFunctionDeclaration(FunctionGenerator.kt:64)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.psi2ir.generators.LocalFunctionGenerator.generateLambda(LocalFunctionGenerator.kt:33)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.psi2ir.generators.StatementGenerator.visitLambdaExpression(StatementGenerator.kt:484)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.psi2ir.generators.StatementGenerator.visitLambdaExpression(StatementGenerator.kt:51)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.psi.KtLambdaExpression.accept(KtLambdaExpression.java:40)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.psi2ir.generators.StatementGenerator.generateStatement(StatementGenerator.kt:67)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.psi2ir.generators.StatementGenerator.generateExpression(StatementGenerator.kt:80)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.psi2ir.generators.ArgumentsGenerationUtilsKt$pregenerateCall$1.invoke(ArgumentsGenerationUtils.kt:515)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.psi2ir.generators.ArgumentsGenerationUtilsKt$pregenerateCall$1.invoke(ArgumentsGenerationUtils.kt:515)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.psi2ir.generators.ArgumentsGenerationUtilsKt.generateValueArgumentUsing(ArgumentsGenerationUtils.kt:378)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.psi2ir.generators.ArgumentsGenerationUtilsKt.pregenerateValueArgumentsUsing(ArgumentsGenerationUtils.kt:765)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.psi2ir.generators.ArgumentsGenerationUtilsKt.pregenerateCallUsing(ArgumentsGenerationUtils.kt:525)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.psi2ir.generators.ArgumentsGenerationUtilsKt.pregenerateCall(ArgumentsGenerationUtils.kt:515)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.psi2ir.generators.StatementGenerator.visitCallExpression(StatementGenerator.kt:362)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.psi2ir.generators.StatementGenerator.visitCallExpression(StatementGenerator.kt:51)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.psi.KtCallExpression.accept(KtCallExpression.java:35)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.psi2ir.generators.StatementGenerator.generateStatement(StatementGenerator.kt:67)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.psi2ir.generators.BodyGenerator.generateLambdaBody(BodyGenerator.kt:112)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.psi2ir.generators.FunctionGenerator.generateLambdaFunctionDeclaration(FunctionGenerator.kt:64)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.psi2ir.generators.LocalFunctionGenerator.generateLambda(LocalFunctionGenerator.kt:33)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.psi2ir.generators.StatementGenerator.visitLambdaExpression(StatementGenerator.kt:484)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.psi2ir.generators.StatementGenerator.visitLambdaExpression(StatementGenerator.kt:51)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.psi.KtLambdaExpression.accept(KtLambdaExpression.java:40)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.psi2ir.generators.StatementGenerator.generateStatement(StatementGenerator.kt:67)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.psi2ir.generators.StatementGenerator.generateExpression(StatementGenerator.kt:80)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.psi2ir.generators.ArgumentsGenerationUtilsKt$pregenerateCall$1.invoke(ArgumentsGenerationUtils.kt:515)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.psi2ir.generators.ArgumentsGenerationUtilsKt$pregenerateCall$1.invoke(ArgumentsGenerationUtils.kt:515)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.psi2ir.generators.ArgumentsGenerationUtilsKt.generateValueArgumentUsing(ArgumentsGenerationUtils.kt:378)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.psi2ir.generators.ArgumentsGenerationUtilsKt.pregenerateValueArgumentsUsing(ArgumentsGenerationUtils.kt:765)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.psi2ir.generators.ArgumentsGenerationUtilsKt.pregenerateCallUsing(ArgumentsGenerationUtils.kt:525)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.psi2ir.generators.ArgumentsGenerationUtilsKt.pregenerateCall(ArgumentsGenerationUtils.kt:515)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.psi2ir.generators.StatementGenerator.visitCallExpression(StatementGenerator.kt:362)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.psi2ir.generators.StatementGenerator.visitCallExpression(StatementGenerator.kt:51)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.psi.KtCallExpression.accept(KtCallExpression.java:35)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.psi2ir.generators.StatementGenerator.generateStatement(StatementGenerator.kt:67)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.psi2ir.generators.BodyGenerator.generateLambdaBody(BodyGenerator.kt:115)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.psi2ir.generators.FunctionGenerator.generateLambdaFunctionDeclaration(FunctionGenerator.kt:64)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.psi2ir.generators.LocalFunctionGenerator.generateLambda(LocalFunctionGenerator.kt:33)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.psi2ir.generators.StatementGenerator.visitLambdaExpression(StatementGenerator.kt:484)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.psi2ir.generators.StatementGenerator.visitLambdaExpression(StatementGenerator.kt:51)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.psi.KtLambdaExpression.accept(KtLambdaExpression.java:40)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.psi2ir.generators.StatementGenerator.generateStatement(StatementGenerator.kt:67)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.psi2ir.generators.StatementGenerator.generateExpression(StatementGenerator.kt:80)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.psi2ir.generators.ArgumentsGenerationUtilsKt$pregenerateCall$1.invoke(ArgumentsGenerationUtils.kt:515)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.psi2ir.generators.ArgumentsGenerationUtilsKt$pregenerateCall$1.invoke(ArgumentsGenerationUtils.kt:515)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.psi2ir.generators.ArgumentsGenerationUtilsKt.generateValueArgumentUsing(ArgumentsGenerationUtils.kt:378)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.psi2ir.generators.ArgumentsGenerationUtilsKt.pregenerateValueArgumentsUsing(ArgumentsGenerationUtils.kt:765)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.psi2ir.generators.ArgumentsGenerationUtilsKt.pregenerateCallUsing(ArgumentsGenerationUtils.kt:525)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.psi2ir.generators.ArgumentsGenerationUtilsKt.pregenerateCall(ArgumentsGenerationUtils.kt:515)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.psi2ir.generators.StatementGenerator.visitCallExpression(StatementGenerator.kt:362)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.psi2ir.generators.StatementGenerator.visitCallExpression(StatementGenerator.kt:51)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.psi.KtCallExpression.accept(KtCallExpression.java:35)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.psi2ir.generators.StatementGenerator.generateStatement(StatementGenerator.kt:67)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.psi2ir.generators.BodyGenerator.generateLambdaBody(BodyGenerator.kt:115)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.psi2ir.generators.FunctionGenerator.generateLambdaFunctionDeclaration(FunctionGenerator.kt:64)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.psi2ir.generators.LocalFunctionGenerator.generateLambda(LocalFunctionGenerator.kt:33)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.psi2ir.generators.StatementGenerator.visitLambdaExpression(StatementGenerator.kt:484)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.psi2ir.generators.StatementGenerator.visitLambdaExpression(StatementGenerator.kt:51)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.psi.KtLambdaExpression.accept(KtLambdaExpression.java:40)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.psi2ir.generators.StatementGenerator.generateStatement(StatementGenerator.kt:67)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.psi2ir.generators.StatementGenerator.generateExpression(StatementGenerator.kt:80)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.psi2ir.generators.ArgumentsGenerationUtilsKt$pregenerateCall$1.invoke(ArgumentsGenerationUtils.kt:515)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.psi2ir.generators.ArgumentsGenerationUtilsKt$pregenerateCall$1.invoke(ArgumentsGenerationUtils.kt:515)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.psi2ir.generators.ArgumentsGenerationUtilsKt.generateValueArgumentUsing(ArgumentsGenerationUtils.kt:378)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.psi2ir.generators.ArgumentsGenerationUtilsKt.pregenerateValueArgumentsUsing(ArgumentsGenerationUtils.kt:765)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.psi2ir.generators.ArgumentsGenerationUtilsKt.pregenerateCallUsing(ArgumentsGenerationUtils.kt:525)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.psi2ir.generators.ArgumentsGenerationUtilsKt.pregenerateCall(ArgumentsGenerationUtils.kt:515)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.psi2ir.generators.StatementGenerator.visitCallExpression(StatementGenerator.kt:362)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.psi2ir.generators.StatementGenerator.visitCallExpression(StatementGenerator.kt:51)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.psi.KtCallExpression.accept(KtCallExpression.java:35)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.psi2ir.generators.StatementGenerator.generateStatement(StatementGenerator.kt:67)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.psi2ir.generators.StatementGenerator.generateStatements(StatementGenerator.kt:77)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.psi2ir.generators.BodyGenerator.generateFunctionBody(BodyGenerator.kt:73)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.psi2ir.generators.FunctionGenerator.generateFunctionDeclaration(FunctionGenerator.kt:52)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.psi2ir.generators.FunctionGenerator.generateFunctionDeclaration$default(FunctionGenerator.kt:41)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.psi2ir.generators.DeclarationGenerator.generateMemberDeclaration(DeclarationGenerator.kt:49)
    ... 46 more
```

build.gradle(Module:app)

```
plugins {
    id 'com.android.application'
    id 'kotlin-android'
    id 'kotlin-kapt'
    id 'dagger.hilt.android.plugin'
}

android {
    compileSdk 33

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.asus.player"
        minSdk 27
        targetSdk 33
        versionCode 3
        versionName "1.0"

        testInstrumentationRunner "androidx.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
        vectorDrawables {
            useSupportLibrary true
        }
    }

    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android-optimize.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
    compileOptions {
        sourceCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
        targetCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
    }
    kotlinOptions {
        jvmTarget = '1.8'
    }
    buildFeatures {
        compose true
    }
    composeOptions {
        kotlinCompilerExtensionVersion '1.2.0'
    }
    packagingOptions {
        resources {
            excludes += '/META-INF/{AL2.0,LGPL2.1}'
        }
    }
}

dependencies {

    implementation 'androidx.core:core-ktx:1.10.1'
    implementation "androidx.compose.ui:ui:$compose_version"
    implementation "androidx.compose.material:material:1.5.0-beta01"
    implementation "androidx.compose.ui:ui-tooling-preview:$compose_version"
    implementation 'androidx.lifecycle:lifecycle-runtime-ktx:2.6.1'
    implementation 'androidx.activity:activity-compose:1.7.1'
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.13.2'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.ext:junit:1.1.5'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.5.1'
    androidTestImplementation "androidx.compose.ui:ui-test-junit4:$compose_version"
    debugImplementation "androidx.compose.ui:ui-tooling:$compose_version"


    // Compose dependencies
    implementation "androidx.lifecycle:lifecycle-viewmodel-compose:2.6.1"
    implementation "androidx.compose.material:material-icons-extended:$compose_version"
    implementation "androidx.hilt:hilt-navigation-compose:1.1.0-alpha01"

    // Coroutines
    //noinspection GradleDependency
    implementation 'org.jetbrains.kotlinx:kotlinx-coroutines-core:1.5.2'
    implementation 'org.jetbrains.kotlinx:kotlinx-coroutines-android:1.7.1'


    //Dagger - Hilt
    implementation "com.google.dagger:hilt-android:2.46.1"
    kapt "com.google.dagger:hilt-android-compiler:2.46.1"
    kapt "androidx.hilt:hilt-compiler:1.0.0"


    //accompanist
    def acc_version = "0.30.1"
    implementation "com.google.accompanist:accompanist-systemuicontroller:$acc_version"
    implementation "com.google.accompanist:accompanist-permissions:$acc_version"
    implementation "com.google.accompanist:accompanist-navigation-animation:$acc_version"
    implementation "com.google.accompanist:accompanist-navigation-material:$acc_version"
    implementation "com.google.accompanist:accompanist-insets:$acc_version"
    //nav
    def nav_compose_version = "2.5.3"
    implementation "androidx.navigation:navigation-compose:$nav_compose_version"


    def exoplayer_version = "2.18.7"
    implementation "com.google.android.exoplayer:exoplayer-core:$exoplayer_version"
    implementation "com.google.android.exoplayer:exoplayer-ui:$exoplayer_version"
    implementation "com.google.android.exoplayer:extension-mediasession:$exoplayer_version"


    //lottie
    def lottieVersion = "4.2.2"
    implementation "com.airbnb.android:lottie-compose:$lottieVersion"

    //coil
    def coilVersion = "2.4.0"
    implementation "io.coil-kt:coil-compose:$coilVersion"
}


kapt {
    correctErrorTypes true
}
```

build.gradle(project):

```
buildscript {
    ext {
        compose_version = '1.4.3'
    }
}// Top-level build file where you can add configuration options common to all sub-projects/modules.
plugins {
    id 'com.android.application' version '7.4.2' apply false
    id 'com.android.library' version '7.4.2' apply false
    id 'org.jetbrains.kotlin.android' version '1.7.0' apply false
    id 'com.google.dagger.hilt.android' version '2.46.1' apply false
}
```

Error is pointing in AnimatedNavHost->enterTransition/exitTransition:

```
                Box(
                    Modifier
                        .fillMaxWidth()
                        .nestedScroll(nestedScrollConnection)
                ) {

                    AnimatedNavHost(
                        navController = navController,
                        startDestination = Screen.HomeScreen.route,
                        enterTransition = {
                            fadeIn(animationSpec = tween(300)) + scaleIn(initialScale = .85f)
                        },
                        exitTransition = {
                            fadeOut(animationSpec = tween(200)) + scaleOut(
                                targetScale = .85f
                            )
                        },

                        ) {

                        composable(Screen.HomeScreen.route) {
                            HomeScreen(songViewModel, bottomSheetState)
                        }

                        composable(Screen.AlbumScreen.route) {
                            val parentEntry = remember(backStackEntry) {
                                navController.getBackStackEntry(Screen.HomeScreen.route)
                            }
                            AlbumScreen(hiltViewModel(parentEntry))
                        }

                        composable(Screen.ArtistsScreen.route) { backStackEntry ->
                            val parentEntry = remember(backStackEntry) {
                                navController.getBackStackEntry(Screen.HomeScreen.route)
                            }
                            ArtistScreen(hiltViewModel<ArtistVieModel>(parentEntry))
                        }

                        composable(Screen.PlayListScreen.route) {
                            PlayListScreen()
                        }
                    }

                    HomeScreenTopBar(
                        route = currentRoute,
                        modifier = Modifier,
                     )
                }
```

Tried this fixes:

- Multiple rounds of clean, rebuild and Invalidate caches, even a system reboot to see if I’d get lucky.
- Changed kotlin versions and gradle versions as many posts were telling that similar issues have been fixed through it.

Comment: Looks like a compiler bug. Try to revert some of the changes you made recently, and find out what caused it. Then report a bug to JetBrains.

Comment: Try Invalidate Caches or Clean > Build Project

Comment: @Jorn It used to work a few months ago but now it's not working. So I am really clueless about what happened in this code :*)

Comment: Well, if it worked before, *something* must have changed: Your code, the build environment, the compiler itself...

Comment: @AnkitTale as I mentioned in the post I have already tried this but it was no good.

Comment: @Jorn So I was trying to get into open source and this was the [project](https://github.com/zeeshanmansoori/aMusicPlayer) that I was trying to run and was able to make one pr but now it has this weird error that's stopping me from doing anything.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had a very similar issue come up and I remembered that `"com.google.accompanist:accompanist-navigation-animation:$acc_version"`  is deprecated now. This [link](https://google.github.io/accompanist/navigation-animation/#:%7E:text=To%20migrate%20from%20using%20the%20Navigation%20Compose%20APIs,com.google.accompanist.navigation.animation.navigation%204%20Replace%20import%20androidx.navigation.compose.composable%20with%20import%20com.google.accompanist.navigation.animation.composable) shows the migration steps. After I made the few changes needed it worked for me. Hopefully this is helpful for others.